# CodeIgniter - modular?

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, architecture, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I'm building several sites that need similar "modules." For example, the sites may have the exact same login system, forum, etc.

Is there a way I could build these modules once and just "drop" them in these various sites? Some of the challenges I see:

- Keeping the code consistent in the various sites. Any changes made to a module should propagate to all of the sites using that module. I guess I need a way to upgrade?
- Database: these functionality need to work as part of a bigger application. Maybe the module needs to define relationships with other tables in its respective site.

I'm sure there are more problems. I think I should be looking at this: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home, but I don't have any experience with it.

So, I'm looking for solutions, suggestions, or more problems to this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and use third party packages by adding them to the third party folder (which is new for CI 2). There is not much about it in the docs, but i found this.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html

You can autoload the third party packages in the autoload file. Packages can have their own controllers, models, views etc.

Interestingly, Phil Sturgeon wrote a bit (http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/04/codeigniter-packages-modules) about packages not being modules (in the strict sense of the term), but you could probably use third party packages for what you need.

Comment: Nick, my problem is that I know that the DB part of these modules I plan to build will need to have relationships with other modules. Meaning, there is a sort of coupling between modules. How to deal with that?

Comment: If you autoload your third party modules, you should be able to use the models in different module controllers. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I dont think they include controllers on each package, but I do know there was a hack somewhere to include it (controllers)

Answer (score 0):

I would write them as libraries and use Git submodules to manage each *module*. Phil Sturgeon actually just wrote a great [post about doing this in CodeIgniter](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2011/09/managing-codeigniter-packages-with-git-submodules).

If you're not using version control, I can't see an easy way to sync across all of your applications. Yes, HMVC will let you break apart your application into actual modules, but it won't help in syncing those modules across your applications.

Comment: I use SVN, but looking into Mercurial. I'm still not sure how I could update just part of a project, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my question about '[Database communication in modular software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539617/database-communication-in-modular-software)'

that you may find useful.

I'm little bit familiar with Drupal, and as a modular application, I think it can be taken as good example of how relationships between modules should be defined.

Here is one good post about [art-of-separation-of-concerns](http://www.aspiringcraftsman.com/2008/01/03/art-of-separation-of-concerns/)

I would like to hear if you have run into some concrete challenges, solutions and references concerning modular design in CI.